# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show all records from database..but when i want to show records the browser show error and the error is:
"

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
>
> Filename: views/show_designation.php
>
> Line Number: 53

Backtrace:
"

View

```
<?php  print_r($designation); $i=1;foreach($designation as $desig): ?>
                                  <tr>
                                       <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>

                                       <td><?php echo $desig['name']; ?></td>  This is (LINE 53)

                                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/designation/delete_designation/'.$desig[$i]->dkey);?>"><input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger"/></a>
                                        <td class="numeric"><a id= "<?php echo $desig[$i]->dkey; ?>"  onclick="edit_designation('<?php echo $designation[$i]->dkey; ?>')" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" style="color:#ffffff;" href="#myModal"><button class="btn blue" type="button">Edit</button>

                                  </tr>
                        <?php $i++;endforeach;?>
```

COntroller

```
public function get_designation()
    {
        $this->load->model('designation_model');
        $userlist=$this->designation_model->get_alldesignation_model();
        $data['designation']=$userlist;
        $this->load->view('show_designation',$data);
    }//edit_project
```

Model

```
public function get_alldesignation_model()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('designations');
        $result=$query->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to use an object as an array(yey, I can read errors, but really now). Since the returned value is an object you need to access the values like you'd do with an object so: `$stdObject->value` NOT `$stdObject['value']`. If you wish to deal with arrays you can convert the object to an array. [See here](stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php) for how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use result of query as array say

```
 $result=$query->result_array();
```

because by default result is returned as object

Answer (score 1):

You are using array syntax where you need object syntax. Replace

```
$desig['name']
```

with

```
$desig->name
```

Note: you will have the same problem in those  lines referring to `$desig[$i]`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but it looks like you are blending some syntax from a `for` loop into your `foreach` loop. If I understand correctly, you simply need to drop the `[$i]` in each place you use it.

Comment: yeah u r right... firstly i use for loop to show records from database..but now i want to change my for loop to foreach loop to show result.

Comment: @farkhund did you try these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in **Model**

```
public function get_alldesignation_model()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('designations');
        $result=$query->result_array();//Store data as Array
        return $result;
    }
```

in **view**

```
<?php 
    $i=1;
    foreach($designation as $desig)
{
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $desig['name']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/designation/delete_designation/'.$desig[$i]->dkey);?>">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger"/>
            </a>
        <td class="numeric"><a id= "<?php echo $desig[$i]->dkey; ?>"  onclick="edit_designation('<?php echo $designation[$i]->dkey; ?>')" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" style="color:#ffffff;" href="#myModal"><button class="btn blue" type="button">Edit</button>

    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```